# Cannot create Account with Customer User

Tags: apex, permissions

I am getting the error `OP_WITH_INVALID_USER_TYPE_EXCEPTION` when trying to create a new Account in Apex Class, i tested both keywords whithout sharing and with sharing, and already added permission to create Accounts in profile, and sharing setting is already setted to Public read/write.

When a verify if this object is creatable with method `Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()`, the method returns `true`;

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Ist your customer user a Chatter Free user? https://sfdctechie.wordpress.com/2019/02/16/op_with_invalid_user_type_exception-from-a-trigger/

Comment: Is a customer community user.

Comment: And what license is in use: "Customer communtiy plus", "partner community" or "customer communty"?

Comment: Just customer community, i read this post and i tried change owner of account with a user that has Standard profile, and works. But it's not the expected behavior of client. Is there way to create with current logged Costomer Community user as Owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obtain your user ID and check if the user has access to the record using the following SOQL query

```
"SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, MaxAccessLevel FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = [User ID] AND RecordId = [Record ID]"
```

Tne exception 'OP_WITH_INVALID_USER_TYPE_EXCEPTION' occurs when an attempt is made to insert the record with a user whose license doesn't allow the creation of that record

So the simple solution is to explicitly set the owner of the new record to some fully-licensed user prior to inserting it or ensure he has access to the object/record that is being inserted